# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, wifi keeps disconnection after 2 minutes of working fine

Tags: networking, wireless, lts

I have to restart my system for it to work for 2 more minutes and after that it just goes blank and shows no networks at all. I am using the "Realtek semiconductor co., ltd.: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter" to have the wifi option.

Comment: Power saving mode?

Comment: There is no specific "Power saving mode," but my power mode is set to "Balanced" instead of "Power Saver."

Comment: Try this, in a terminal window run the following commands `sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` and when the file opens change the value of `wifi.powersave` from 3 to 2. After that do a reboot and check whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

The default "driver" for for your WiFi chipset is quite unreliable.

Open Additional Drivers, select the one offered, apply and reboot. Or manually install it in Terminal:

```
sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

Comment: E: Unable to locate package rt18821ce-dkms

Comment: The package name starts with rtl with a small L not a 1

Comment: It worked. Just hoping that it won't disconnect after 2 minutes anymore. Thank you!

Comment: @HarishJoshi If the answer was useful please accept it when convenient. That's how the site works :)

Comment: It didn't work. I have updated the driver but the problem remains the same...

Comment: If so the problem is with the network you're connecting to or the laptop's hardware.